# Enable Kestrel service on centos exited (code=exited, status=145)

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment, reverse-proxy, centos7, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to deploy an aspnet core application on CentOs 7
I followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) untill I enable and check the status of the kestrel-myapp.service using 
`systemctl status kestrel.-myapp.service` then I get the error `ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /path-to-dll (code=exited, status=145)`

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and eventually tracked it down to some sort of path security or length issue from this post -> https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4038
When I ran the dotnet app, it ran fine, even with www-data.
But it seems that when I ran it with its full path it threw a "realpath(): Not a directory" error.
I previously had my application set up in a long-winded path with additional security, but I moved it to /opt/myapp and it worked fine.